# Safe to call `projectPoint(_:)` during `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)`?

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos, scenekit

1. SceneKit's `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)` operates on a background thread.
2. Apple has said not to call any methods on `NSView` and subclasses outside the main thread.
3. `projectPoint(_:)` seems frequently useful during `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)`... but don't 1. and 2. mean it's not safe to call it?

Comment: Do you have a link/citation for point #1?

Comment: @HalMueller Sure: `print(NSThread.isMainThread()) //prints "false"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's not well supported is calling AppKit or UIKit methods in secondary threads.

`-projectPoint:` is a method of the `SCNSceneRenderer` protocol and it is safe to call it in the delegate method even if it's not on the main thread.